# Suppress Ansible Ad Hoc Warning

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I have a python script that takes advantage of an Ansible ad hoc command to get host information quickly. I'd like to suppress the warning when I'm attempting to gather information about a host that is in a different VPC, but shows in the following command used to find all instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

Below is the python snippet I'm using to make and generate the ansible ad hoc command:

```
command_string = "ansible -i /repo/ansible/inventory/"+env+"/hosts " + name + " -m shell -a 'df -h'"
result = subprocess.Popen(command_string, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

I understand that in a playbook setting for the shell module:

```
warn=no
```

will disable warnings, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so via adhoc, see below test:

```
[root@box-1b 10.0.5.xxx:~] ansible -i /repo/ansible/inventory/nqa/hosts 10.19.1.17 -m shell -a 'warn=no'
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do

[root@box-1b 10.0.5.xxx:~] ansible -i /repo/ansible/inventory/nqa/hosts 10.19.1.17 -m shell -a 'warn=false'
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

The output of my full script looks similar to the following:

```
i-xxxxxx
    my-super-cool-box
    t2.small    True
    10.0.0.10
    vol-xxxxxxx
    100
    i-xxxxxxx
    /dev/xvdf


 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

The information printed about the specific instance is correct, and all I'm looking for is a way to suppress that warning without changing the global ansible configurations.

Comment: Thinking to use http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script

Answer (score 4):

This is worked for me `ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER=auto_silent`

example: `ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER=auto_silent ansible -i /repo/ansible/inventory/nqa/hosts 10.19.1.17 -m shell -a "uptime"`

Answer (score 3):

This warning has nothing common with `command`/`shell` module warnings, which you can control with `warn: no`.

This warning is printed by `adhoc` CLI when you provide host pattern that doesn't match any host from your inventory.

In your example host `10.19.1.17` is not defined in `/repo/ansible/inventory/nqa/hosts` inventory, so Ansible gives you warning that there's nothing to do.

Make sure that either you run Ansible with hosts that do exist in your static inventory file, or setup [ec2 dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) and run Ansible against all EC2 instances or filter by tag, security_group, etc.

Comment: Do you know how to disable the `command`/`shell` warnings when running ad-hoc? (In other words, similar question to OP, but in the actual circumstance of the eg 'consider using the service module instead...' type warnings).

Comment: Yes, `warn: no`: https://ansibledaily.com/avoid-ansible-command-warnings/

Comment: That’s when running in a playbook - I’m trying to figure out how to provide the warn argument when running adhoc- ie on the command line to `ansible` - because eg. `ansible --module shell --args “warn=No service httpd stop”` is not picked up, because the command to run doesn’t actually have an argument name...

Comment: What's the difference between `warn: no` and `args: warn: false`?

Comment: @TimMalone try putting the args last :     `ansible --module shell --args "service httpd stop warn=no"`

Comment: @TimMalone this worked for me `ansible hostname     -a "service httpd status warn=false"`

Answer (score 3):

set env variable `ANSIBLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` to `false` like this:

```sh
ANSIBLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=false ansible -i /path/to/inventory hosts -a your_command
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ANSIBLE_COMMAND_WARNINGS=false ansible ...
ANSIBLE_COMMAND_WARNINGS=no ansible ...
```